Why in Genesis 1 all is good and Gen 2 all is "not good"?
In Genesis 1, God testifies consistently that everything He created ranged from good to very good.
In Genesis 2, on the other hand, everything goes haywire: Adam is created not perfect, and his loneliness is deemed "not good", causing God to create animals, that were again "not good" for him. Finally, God creates Eve and we all know how badly the story ended (Gen 3).
It appears that in Gen 1 God knows what He's doing and enjoys the fruits of His creation, while in Gen 2, He consistently changes His mind and tries to fix it.
Why such a stark contrast?

Can it be connected with using YHWH Elohim instead of Elohim alone as God's name?
Can it reflect the difference between the ideal world of בריאה (creation) and our less-than-ideal material world of יצירה (formation)?

NB: I found a related question about the differences in the narrative.

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_3.2.7?lang=he

@JoelK I would expect God saying "not good being Adam alone" and then forming him etc. The narrative us different - God creates Adan, interacts with him and only then realizes "it's not good".

R Albo's question is, I think, why the animals were judged as "good" immediately upon creation, but man was not (there is no וירא אלקים כי טוב for the creation of man in chapter 1). He's not really focusing on the narrative in chapter 2, which is why I left this as a comment only.

@JoelK Right, thank you!

Hashem didn’t create animals after Adam’s loneliness. He just took ones that were already there from Gen. 1.

@QwertyCTRL. I don't follow. The text says God formed animals and brought them to Adam. What was this second forming?

When discussing the other elements of the physical universe aside from mankind, the Torah seems satisfied to inform us that Hashem made them, and they are as He intended them to be, which is indeed very good.  It is not necessary for the Torah to teach us deeply about the nature of fishes or mountains or birds, as none of these things impact on the purpose of the Torah, which is to teach us how to be human beings.  To the extent that it is useful to us to learn about these physical elements of our world, we should get up and investigate the world, observe it and learn.
But when it comes to humanity, the Torah indeed needs to teach us about the nature of humanity, which is our nature, because this impacts profoundly on the purpose of the Torah.  And so here we are informed that "it is not good for man to be alone," that men are fundamentally and unbridgably apart from the animal world, about the risks of social interaction, and more.
All of these things are part of the task for which the Torah was created; namely, to teach us how to be the human beings that Hashem had in mind, both as a species and as individuals.  And so here, it is not enough to say that in the big picture it is "very good."  Rather, here the Torah must go into details and teach us about different ways in which we might fail, so that we can learn from the text and avoid the experience.

Thank you. I appreciate your zeal. The quality of your answer can be greatly improved if you support your statements with appropriate sources, like "according to the book X of rabbi Y..." or "the Gemmorah in X says that ...". Also your answer does not address the fact that the man is mentioned in Gen 1 for good.

Actually, there is one aspect in Genesis 1 that is not good. The second day of creation is not called good by God. There is no mention of good in Genesis 1:6-8 concerning the second day. However, the third day makes up for this with two labels of good.
Seems as though Genesis 1 is a creation account from the "heavenly" perspective, (Genesis 1:1) since Genesis 2's creation account is from an "earthly" perspective. Earth is first before Heaven in the latter part of Genesis 2:4. Adam is also created first according to Genesis 2 (unlike in Genesis 1), so from man's point of view, it does seem as though things are not good and that they need to be fixed. Man has a very limited perspective.
The heavenly perspective in Genesis 1 transcends time and is probably already looking at the Messianic era of the year 6000 AM. Hence why everything is good and in order according to chapter 1.
This is just my guess though. Feel free to disagree.

According to the documentary hypothesis, Gen. 1 and Gen. 2 are from two different authors. While most Orthodox Jews reject the this hypothesis, several Orthodox rabbis have begun to do so.  Many Conservative and Reform rabbis accept it.
The hypothesis indeed focuses on the fact that "YHWH Elohim" is the name of God in Gen. 2 while simply Elohim alone as is God's name in Gen 1. Scholars who uphold this view hold that Gen. 1 was composed somewhat later than Gen. 2 and expresses the idea of God's absolute sovereignty over all creation. Gen. 2 expresses a time (possibly during the reign of King Hezekiah) when both female deities and snake gods still represented a threat. Thus the woman and the serpent are presented as opposed to God's will in Gen. 2, while in Gen. 1 - as the OP points out - "all is good."

Thank you, this is definitely a very straightforward way to reconcile discrepancies.
